# NoClassDefFoundError javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart$MimePartDataHandler in Android

Tags: android, google-api, noclassdeffounderror, gmail-api, jakarta-mail

I'm getting NoClassDefFoundError in an Android app I'm writing. 
I added:

```
compile 'javax.mail:mail:1.4.7'
```

to my build.gradle. But I get a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError exception trying to run this code:

```
MimeMessage email = new MimeMessage(session, new ByteArrayInputStream(decodedRawMessage));
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Got mimeType: "+email.getContent());
```

The "email.getContent()" is the place where the exception is thrown.
Is there a different version of javax.mail I should use?

Comment: if you are using android studio did you try to sync project with gradle files

Comment: @DreadfulWeather Of course

Answer (score 1):

Eventually I didn't use the 'compile' line in gradle. I added jars the old way in the libs folder and clicked 'Add as Library' from the right click menu in Android Studio. Jars can be downloaded from [here](https://code.google.com/p/javamail-android/downloads/list)

Need all **3** of them.